# Kubuntu 20.04 Kernel crash

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, lenovo, crash

I'v been presenting some issues with my fresh install of Kubuntu 20.04, the system freezes and after reading the output from journalctl I found that it is due to some "Kernel Crash". Maybe someone knows how yo solve this.

I'm gonna leave the output of `journalctl`

```
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: BUG: unable to handle page fault for address: 000000000000d960
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: #PF: supervisor read access in kernel mode
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0000) - not-present page
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 724 Comm: Xorg Not tainted 5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 80T6/00RD15IPG075, BIOS 1GCN19WW 10/03/2016
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RIP: 0010:__i915_schedule+0x261/0x350 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: Code: ff a8 08 0f 84 a0 00 00 00 45 3b b4 24 18 04 00 00 7e 50 49 8b 84 24 d8 03 00 00 48 8b 00 48 85 c0 74 40 48 8b b3 30 ff ff ff <48> 39 70 60 74 33 45 89 b4 24 18 04 00 00 8b 80 60 01 00 00 be 00
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb0ff0104f8b8 EFLAGS: 00010006
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RAX: 000000000000d900 RBX: ffff989a00e3c8b0 RCX: ffff9899f17ef5f0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RDX: ffff989a00e3c8d0 RSI: ffff989a3104f400 RDI: ffff989a00e3c8b0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RBP: ffffb0ff0104f950 R08: ffffb0ff0104f898 R09: ffff9898e257eea0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: R10: 0000000000005000 R11: ffff989a2f98ff00 R12: ffff989a3a83a000
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: R13: ffffb0ff0104f8c8 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: ffff9899f17ef5f0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: FS:  00007f07e70b7a80(0000) GS:ffff989a3ba00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: CR2: 000000000000d960 CR3: 000000016d3a4000 CR4: 00000000001006f0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: Call Trace:
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  __i915_sched_node_add_dependency+0x140/0x150 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  i915_sched_node_add_dependency+0x44/0x80 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  i915_request_await_dma_fence+0x11a/0x320 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  i915_request_await_object+0xc8/0x1d0 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? i915_vma_move_to_active+0x66/0x150 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  eb_submit+0x293/0x440 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  i915_gem_do_execbuffer+0x88e/0xc20 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? fwtable_read32+0x90/0x200 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? store_vblank+0x40/0x70 [drm]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? drm_update_vblank_count+0x117/0x240 [drm]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? __kmalloc_node+0x20e/0x330
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  i915_gem_execbuffer2_ioctl+0x1eb/0x3d0 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? i915_gem_madvise_ioctl+0x164/0x2a0 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? i915_gem_execbuffer_ioctl+0x2d0/0x2d0 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  drm_ioctl_kernel+0xae/0xf0 [drm]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  drm_ioctl+0x234/0x3d0 [drm]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? i915_gem_execbuffer_ioctl+0x2d0/0x2d0 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? enqueue_hrtimer+0x3d/0x90
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  do_vfs_ioctl+0x407/0x670
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? fput+0x13/0x15
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ? __sys_recvmsg+0x88/0xa0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  ksys_ioctl+0x67/0x90
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  __x64_sys_ioctl+0x1a/0x20
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f07e741737b
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: Code: 0f 1e fa 48 8b 05 15 3b 0d 00 64 c7 00 26 00 00 00 48 c7 c0 ff ff ff ff c3 66 0f 1f 44 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa b8 10 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d e5 3a 0d 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RSP: 002b:00007fffeab68ce8 EFLAGS: 00003246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000010
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 00007fffeab68d30 RCX: 00007f07e741737b
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RDX: 00007fffeab68d30 RSI: 0000000040406469 RDI: 000000000000000f
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RBP: 0000000040406469 R08: 000000000000000f R09: 000055f43f723e30
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000003246 R12: 000055f43f6e13c0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: R13: 000000000000000f R14: ffffffffffffffff R15: 00007f07e69da4c8
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio videobuf2_vmalloc intel_rapl_msr videobuf2_memops intel_rapl_common videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg ath10k_pci videobuf2_common snd_hda_codec videodev snd_hda_core rtsx_usb_ms intel_powerclamp mc snd_hwdep snd_pcm memstick ath10k_core snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event coretemp ath snd_rawmidi btusb mac80211 btrtl btbcm btintel snd_seq bluetooth mei_hdcp cfg80211 ideapad_laptop ecdh_generic kvm_intel ecc intel_xhci_usb_role_switch kvm snd_seq_device snd_timer roles libarc4 sparse_keymap wmi_bmof snd intel_int0002_vgpio punit_atom_debug intel_cstate soundcore mei_txe mei joydev input_leds serio_raw mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel:  crypto_simd syscopyarea sysfillrect cryptd sysimgblt glue_helper psmouse fb_sys_fops r8169 i2c_i801 drm lpc_ich realtek ahci libahci wmi video hid_generic usbhid hid
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: CR2: 000000000000d960
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: ---[ end trace a10a50514ff3aaaf ]---
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RIP: 0010:__i915_schedule+0x261/0x350 [i915]
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: Code: ff a8 08 0f 84 a0 00 00 00 45 3b b4 24 18 04 00 00 7e 50 49 8b 84 24 d8 03 00 00 48 8b 00 48 85 c0 74 40 48 8b b3 30 ff ff ff <48> 39 70 60 74 33 45 89 b4 24 18 04 00 00 8b 80 60 01 00 00 be 00
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb0ff0104f8b8 EFLAGS: 00010006
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RAX: 000000000000d900 RBX: ffff989a00e3c8b0 RCX: ffff9899f17ef5f0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RDX: ffff989a00e3c8d0 RSI: ffff989a3104f400 RDI: ffff989a00e3c8b0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: RBP: ffffb0ff0104f950 R08: ffffb0ff0104f898 R09: ffff9898e257eea0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: R10: 0000000000005000 R11: ffff989a2f98ff00 R12: ffff989a3a83a000
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: R13: ffffb0ff0104f8c8 R14: 0000000000000003 R15: ffff9899f17ef5f0
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: FS:  00007f07e70b7a80(0000) GS:ffff989a3ba00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
sep 14 12:48:01 multivac kernel: CR2: 000000000000d960 CR3: 000000016d3a4000 CR4: 00000000001006f0
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 23s! [ksysguardd:1276]
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio videobuf2_vmalloc intel_rapl_msr videobuf2_memops intel_rapl_common videobuf2_v4l2 snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg ath10k_pci videobuf2_common snd_hda_codec videodev snd_hda_core rtsx_usb_ms intel_powerclamp mc snd_hwdep snd_pcm memstick ath10k_core snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event coretemp ath snd_rawmidi btusb mac80211 btrtl btbcm btintel snd_seq bluetooth mei_hdcp cfg80211 ideapad_laptop ecdh_generic kvm_intel ecc intel_xhci_usb_role_switch kvm snd_seq_device snd_timer roles libarc4 sparse_keymap wmi_bmof snd intel_int0002_vgpio punit_atom_debug intel_cstate soundcore mei_txe mei joydev input_leds serio_raw mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_usb_sdmmc rtsx_usb i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  crypto_simd syscopyarea sysfillrect cryptd sysimgblt glue_helper psmouse fb_sys_fops r8169 i2c_i801 drm lpc_ich realtek ahci libahci wmi video hid_generic usbhid hid
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 1276 Comm: ksysguardd Tainted: G      D           5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 80T6/00RD15IPG075, BIOS 1GCN19WW 10/03/2016
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RIP: 0010:smp_call_function_single+0x9b/0x110
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: Code: 65 8b 05 30 85 6c 62 a9 00 01 1f 00 75 79 85 c9 75 40 48 c7 c6 00 bc 02 00 65 48 03 35 e6 1c 6c 62 8b 46 18 a8 01 74 09 f3 90 <8b> 46 18 a8 01 75 f7 83 4e 18 01 4c 89 c9 4c 89 c2 e8 7f fe ff ff
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb0ff0184fba0 EFLAGS: 00000202 ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffff13
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: 000000003bd7e271 RCX: 0000000000000000
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: ffff989a3bbabc00 RDI: 0000000000000003
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RBP: ffffb0ff0184fbe8 R08: ffffffff9d848960 R09: 0000000000000000
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: R10: 0000000000000001 R11: 006f666e69757063 R12: 0000000000000003
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: R13: 000009666cdfbf35 R14: 0000000000000001 R15: ffff989a38d02400
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: FS:  00007f5c84437740(0000) GS:ffff989a3bb80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: CR2: 00007f3300350070 CR3: 0000000178190000 CR4: 00000000001006e0
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: Call Trace:
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  ? number+0x321/0x370
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  ? ktime_get+0x3e/0xa0
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  aperfmperf_snapshot_cpu+0x42/0x50
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  arch_freq_prepare_all+0x67/0xa0
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  cpuinfo_open+0x13/0x30
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  proc_reg_open+0x77/0x130
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  ? proc_put_link+0x10/0x10
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  do_dentry_open+0x143/0x3a0
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  vfs_open+0x2d/0x30
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  do_last+0x194/0x900
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  path_openat+0x8d/0x290
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  ? touch_atime+0x33/0xe0
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  do_filp_open+0x91/0x100
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  ? __alloc_fd+0x46/0x150
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  do_sys_open+0x17e/0x290
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  __x64_sys_openat+0x20/0x30
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  do_syscall_64+0x57/0x190
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel:  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RIP: 0033:0x7f5c84699d1b
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: Code: 25 00 00 41 00 3d 00 00 41 00 74 4b 64 8b 04 25 18 00 00 00 85 c0 75 67 44 89 e2 48 89 ee bf 9c ff ff ff b8 01 01 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 00 f0 ff ff 0f 87 91 00 00 00 48 8b 4c 24 28 64 48 33 0c 25
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RSP: 002b:00007ffc827740a0 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 0000000000000101
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 000055afc4223bc0 RCX: 00007f5c84699d1b
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 000055afc2a79e64 RDI: 00000000ffffff9c
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: RBP: 000055afc2a79e64 R08: 00007ffc827ba080 R09: 00007ffc82774128
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
sep 14 12:48:26 multivac kernel: R13: 000055afc4223bf0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: 0000000000000000
sep 14 12:48:54 multivac kernel: watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#3 stuck for 22s! [ksysguardd:1276]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have page fault errors, and video driver errors.

**BIOS**

LENOVO 80T6/00RD15IPG075

You have BIOS version 1GCN19WW from 10/03/2016.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 1GCN25WW from May 23, 2018, and it can be downloaded [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/100-series/110-14ibr/80t6/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**memtest**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: I'm gonna do the BIOS update at weekend. How can I fix the video driver errors? If i understand, Ubuntu install the most recent and best drivers for my Processor (I don't have a dedicated GPU).

Comment: @JuliánD.Sorel I'm hoping that the BIOS update will solve both problems.